# VS 2017 User Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm new to VS2017 and I can't find the Settings tab. In the older VS, I could find settings in Project>Properties or by right-clicking the project in solution explorer, and clicking properties. When I do that in VS2017, all of the other tabs seem to be there - just no settings tab.

I found a site that said I should right-click the project in Solution Explorer, and Add a Settings file. But that doesn't seem to be an option.

When I type "My.Settings", Intellisense says 'settings' is not a member...

I really just need to be able to save a few integers, decimals, strings, etc. Am I supposed to save them to file instead of settings?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a settings file to your project. Right click on the project, select "Add -> New Item".  The file type is a "Settings File".

Once added, you can then add your integers, decimals, string, etc.

IIRC, previous versions only allowed for one settings file, but now that it's broken out, you could create multiple settings files and group them logically, if so desried.